# Assembler How work with index in db Beginner

Tags: assembly, indexing, 8051

I have a one problem, I don't know how to get step by step index from db:C here is my code:

```
    Morse:
                        mov  DPTR, #Text     ; Point to the beginning of the text
                            mov  A, R0 ;offset to acc
    
    NextChar:
                        movc A, @A+DPTR            ; Load a character from the text into register A
                            cjne A, #2Eh, EndProgram   ;check for dot
                            cjne A, #20h, WordSpace    ;check for space
                        cjne A, #00h, CharLoop     ; Check if the character is not null (end of text)
                        jmp  EndProgram            ; Otherwise, move to the next character in the text  !!!!!!!!HOW TO CHECK IF IT NULL!!!!!!!!!!!

    CharLoop:
                            orl  A, #20h
                            clr  C ;clear C flag after orl
                            subb A, #61h
                            mov  DPTR, #ASCII_TO_MORSE_TABLE
                            movc A, @A+DPTR
                            ;mov  R4, A     ; R4 = Code MORSE
                            inc  R0;             ; counter chars at Text
                            mov  R2, #00h  ; counter dot\dash in char
                            jmp DotORDash

  DotORDash:
                            ; here at A,B,R4 I have for example "--.-!"
                            ; How here load to A just first char from, A,B,R4?
                            movc A, @A+DPTR
                            inc R2 ; "which char morse ++"
                            cjne A, #21h, Morse; if r4 == "!" jmp Morse
                            cjne A, #2Dh, DASH; if r4 == "-" call DASH
                            cjne A, #2Eh, DOT; if r4 == "." call DOT
                            jmp Morse

ASCII_TO_MORSE_TABLE:db     '.-!', '-...!', '-.-.!', '-..!',    '.!', '..-.!', '--.!',  '....!', '..!', '.---!', '-.-!', '.-..!',   '--!', '-.!', '---!', '.--.!', '--.-!', '.-.!', '...!', '-!', '..-!', '...-!', '.--!', '-..-!', '-.--!', '--..!', '-----!', '.----!', '..---!', '...--!', '....-!', '.....!', '-....!', '--...!', '---..!', ' ----.!' 
                                                    ; | a  | |  b   | |  c  |    |  d    |  |e|   |  f  |  | g   |  |  h   | | i  | |  j   | |  k  | |  l  |  | m  | | n  | |  o  | |  p  |  |  q  |  |  r |  |  s  | | t | |  u |  |  v  |  |  w  | |  x  |  |  y  |  |  z  |  |   0  |  |   1  |  |   2  |  |   3  |   |  4  |  |   5  |  |   6  |  |   7  |   |   8  |  |   9  |
```

So the main problem for me its how at DotORDash get step by step chars, for example I have at B,A,R4 this value: '.-!', how I can at DotORDash get step by step these values?

Comment: 8051? Be sure to tag your question with the appropriate architecture to attrack the right people to it.

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "at A,B,R4". Anyway just set `DPTR` to where the thing is and increment it in a loop. Make sure you zero `A` since the address is `A+DPTR`.

Comment: BTW I believe cjne is compare and jump if **not** equal, so I don't think your instructions match the comments in DotORDash.

Comment: @Jester the main problem is that I get from here : "ASCII_TO_MORSE_TABLE:db '.-!', ... " code for Morse code. in the code itself in A I already have this set '.-!' and I don't know how to put it in DPTR

Comment: This question has nothing to do with database and indexing. You have only provided part of the code. What does ASCII_TO_MORSE_TABLE look like? It is key information for creating an algorithm  to determine the beginning of the Morse code for a some letter.

Comment: One version of their `ASCII_TO_MORSE_TABLE` was defined in the OP's previous question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77167058/how-to-work-with-index-of-db-in-assembler), which they deleted after Jester gave a useful suggestion in comments of making the entries fixed-width so you can index them as an array with `ascii_char - 'A'`, or that linear searching could work as long as your key isn't a `.` `-` or ` `.  But anyway, its missing from this question so it's not a good [mcve].

Comment: @PeterPlesník "db" does not mean "data base" here, but "define byte". It is a pseudo instruction that places the given expression(s) in the memory.

Comment: I know, I mean the `database` tag set for this question, not the `db` in the code.

Comment: @PeterPlesník I see. Well, I'm gonna remove that.

Answer (score 0):

The code is written on the fly, it has not been compiled, its task is to show the algorithm for finding the beginning of the morse code for any alpha character.

First of all, you need to understand how the `cjne` instruction works.
Subsequently, it is necessary to realize that this is not about any database manipulations (please remove the `database` and `indexing` tags), but about linear searching of text strings with using a pointer.

The rest should be clear from the source text itself.

```
Morse:
                        mov  DPTR, #Text     ; Point to the beginning of the text
                        mov  A, R0           ;offset to acc
    
NextChar:
                        movc A, @A+DPTR      ; Load a character from the text into register A
                        inc  r0
                        cjne A, #'.', nextTest01   ;check for dot
                        rjmp endProgram
nextTest01:             cjne A, #' ', nextTest02
                        rjmp WordSpace    ;check for space
notAlpha:               jmp Morse
nextTest02:             jz   EndProgram   ; Check if the character is not null (end of text)

;A is character to decode 
                        mov r3,a          ;R3 temp register
                        clr c
                        subb a,#'A'
                        jc notAlpha
                        mov a,r3
                        setb c
                        subb a,#'z'
                        jnc notAplha
                        mov a,r3
;A is alphabet character from range 'A - z' (not tested special chars)
                        orl  A, #20h      ;convert to lowercase
                        clr  C            ;clear C flag after orl
                        subb A, #'a'      ;calculate the sequence number of the character
                        mov  DPTR, #ASCII_TO_MORSE_TABLE ;set pointer to first char ('a')
                        jz  morseCode
                        mov r3,a
;find start morse code for next char
;increasing pointer in loop until separate char '!' is not find
noSeparateChar:         clr a
                        movc A, @A+DPTR
                        inc dptr                   ;move to next char
                        cjne a,#'!',noSeparateChar ;repeat until separator is not find
                        djnz r3, noSeparateChar    ;repeat until find requested char

morseCode:
; DPTR now point to start of morse code sequence

                        clr a
                        movc A, @A+DPTR
                        inc dptr ;move pointer to next morse char
                        cjne A, #'!', nextTest03
                        rjmp Morse ; if '!' then process next char of message
nextTest03:             cjne A, #'-', DOT ;if dot make somethnig (no others chars as '.' are enabled)
                        jmp DASH ; if '-' make something

;table must not contain digit.
;you must create separate table for digits and make similar search as for chars
ASCII_TO_MORSE_TABLE:db     '.-!', '-...!', '-.-.!', '-..!',    '.!', '..-.!', '--.!',  '....!', '..!', '.---!', '-.-!', '.-..!',   '--!', '-.!', '---!', '.--.!', '--.-!', '.-.!', '...!', '-!', '..-!', '...-!', '.--!', '-..-!', '-.--!', '--..!' 
                                                    ; | a  | |  b   | |  c  |    |  d    |  |e|   |  f  |  | g   |  |  h   | | i  | |  j   | |  k  | |  l  |  | m  | | n  | |  o  | |  p  |  |  q  |  |  r |  |  s  | | t | |  u |  |  v  |  |  w  | |  x  |  |  y  |  |  z  |
```